# dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 method return different timezone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

The timezone will change, when I put different seconds in `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:`

Here is the code :

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:format];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]]; //Asia/shanghai +8:00
int64_t timestamp = 714880800 ;//  683258400
NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp];
NSString *str = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

I make timestamp = **714880800** the first time, and then **683258400** the second time, but the result is that:
the date description:

```
1992-08-27 02:00:00 +0000
1991-08-27 02:00:00 +0000
```

[image]

[image]

Why is the timezone different? Is there something I have missed?

Comment: That first "timestamp" value is Thu, 27 Aug 1992 02:00:00 GMT.  What did you expect?  (Remember, an NSDate is *always* UTC.)

Comment: @HotLicks I know it is UTC, the second value of "timestamp" is 1991-08-27 02:00:00 +0000 ,but why the timezone changed,look at the second "date":the timezone became "CDT" from "CST"

Comment: Could [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_China): "After the Chinese Civil War, in 1949, a unified time zone—GMT+8—was established by the People's Republic of China for all its territories, called Beijing Time (sometimes known as Chinese Standard Time). Daylight saving time was observed from 1986 to 1991." have something to do with it? If you're calculating Shanghai local, I'd expect an August local datetime to be daylight saving in 1991, but not in 1992.

Comment: @MattGibson yeah,i checkout some information about CDT,that China had using CDT during 1986 and 1991.so the timezone Standard change from CST to CDT,and time +1hour.it had been canceled in 1992 then!

Answer (score 1):

NSDate objects represent a single point in time. It doesn't contain any time zone information.

Xcode try to express the NSDate object with a specific time zone, because a time is meaningless without a time zone.

The fact that Xcode use a different time zone for different `NSDate` object may try to tell you "Hey, the NSDate has nothing to do with time zone, I just use it to express a time, that's all".

Edit: Log it out.

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"] ;
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSTimeInterval timestamp = 714880800 ;
NSDate* date1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp];
NSLog(@"%@", date1) ;
NSString *str = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date1] ;
NSLog(@"%@", str) ;
```

You will get :

```
1992-08-27 02:00:00 +0000 <<<< add by myself (GMT)
1992-08-27 10:00:00       <<<< add by myself (CCT)
```

Comment: i set the timezone by:[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];(+8:00) how can I get the correct string of the date in my timezone

Comment: at first time ,it is right,the timezone:CST(+8:00),but the second time ,it changes to CDT(+9:00)

Comment: yeah,the first time is right , then try NSTimeInterval timestamp = 683258400.i will get the result "1991-08-27 11:00:00 "

Comment: @Dean That's right. `1991-08-27 02:00:00 +0000 GMT` `1991-08-27 11:00:00 CCT`

Comment: I know the time is right ,but my timezone is (+8:00),and i did not change the timezone,why it changed to (+9:00),if i log out the str,it will give me a wrong string:"1991-08-27 11:00:00",which i need is "1991-08-27 10:00:00"

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that. First time I say `1992-08-27 02:00:00 +0000` is GMT because `1992-08-27 10:00:00` is CCT. Second time we get `1991-08-27 02:00:00 +0000`, I think maybe Xcode won't use GMT permanently. I don't know what the method `description` of NSDate does, but I think `1991-08-27 11:00:00` is right.

Comment: i guess it is something about "Daylight Saving Time：DST",china use it between 1986-1991,during the "DST", timezone would +1,it had been canceled in 1992.in xcode,the timezone never changed after 1992.BTW,thank you so much